# Finding tangent points of an ellipse given an exterior point

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

There are two tangents from the point $P = (\frac{1261}{20},-1)$ to the ellipse with equation $\frac{x^2}{169}+\frac{y^2}{25} = 1.$

Determine the coordinates of the points, $E$ and $F$, where the tangents touch this ellipse. All coordinates should be correct to two decimal places.

So far I have found the slope to be $\frac{-25x}{169y}$. Is it right to say the equation is $y+1 = \frac{-25x}{169y}\left(x-\frac{1261}{20}\right)$ ? I attempted to sub this equation of a line into the ellipse equation to get the points, but i still have two variables? All help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it right to say the equation is $y+1 = \frac{-25x}{169y}\left(x-\frac{1261}{20}\right)$

No, that's not correct. When you say you've found the slope to be $\frac{-25x}{169y}$, you need to be much more precise. What you know is that if a line is tangent to the ellipse at a point $(a, b)$ (*which is on the ellipse*, of course), then the slope of that line is $\frac{-25a}{169b}$. That means the equation of the line is 
$$
y - b = \frac{-25a}{169b}(x-a).
$$

Notice that I did *not* use "$(x, y)$" as the point of tangency to the ellipse, because $(x, y)$ is used to denote a generic point of the tangent line, and only *one* of those points is on the ellipse.

So right there is where your approach went off the rails.

Let me suggest a different starting point:

Construct a line from $(1261/20, -1)$ to an arbitrary point $(a, b)$ on the ellipse. Determine the slope of the line, and compare this to the slope of the ellipse at $(a, b)$. For certain values of $(a, b)$, these two will be equal, and for those points, you've got a tangent line rather than a secant line.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the polar's equation to 
$$\frac{\frac{1261}{20}\cdot x}{169}+\frac{-1\cdot y}{25}=1$$
first, solve for 
$$y=25\left(\frac{97}{260}x-1\right)$$
and plug that in the equation of the ellipse to get 
$$x=\frac{16}{5}\quad\text{or}\quad x=\frac{312}{145}.$$